# How to bind the Xml data without attribute values to the TreeView control?

Tags: wpf, xml, binding, tags, treeview

I need to bind the xml data to treeview  just with the tagnames.
example:

```
  <Tools>
     <Bin>
          <EAN128u.dll /> 
          <NetSet.dll /> 
          <MaxicodeWizardu.dll /> 
          <HIBC.dll /> 
      </Bin>
```

I have a xml which  describes the TreeView control view. So the TreeView nodes must have the names of tags. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317766/Displaying-XML-in-a-WPF-TreeView

This tutorial walks through adding XML data to a Tree View.

Comment: No, there we have an attributes. I have just empty tags.

Comment: Either way it looks like you need to define a template for how the tree hierarchy. This is an example of creating a template.            http://blogs.intuidev.com/post/2009/12/28/XML_To_TreeView.aspx